# MySQLi why am I only getting 1 result?

Tags: php, mysqli

There are three "BC" in the result_category but I am only getting 1 result. This is for a personality quiz. Please Help. I also tried $query = "SELECT result FROM quiz_map where result_category = 'BC'"; but still, only 1 result is showing.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

$cat_a = $cat_b = $cat_c = $cat_d = $cat_e = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    $cat = $row['category'];
    if ($cat == "A") {
        $cat_a += 1;
    } elseif ($cat == "B") {
        $cat_b += 1;
    } elseif ($cat == "C") {
        $cat_c += 1;
    } elseif ($cat == "D") {
        $cat_d += 1;
    } elseif ($cat == "E") {
        $cat_e += 1;
    }
}

$array = array('A' => $cat_a, 'B' => $cat_b, 'C' => $cat_c, 'D' => $cat_d, 'E' => $cat_e);
$str = '';

foreach ($array as $i => $value) {
    if ($value >= 6) {      
        $str = $i;
        break;
    } elseif ($value >= 2) {        
        $str .= $i;
    }
}

$var = sort($array);

$query = "SELECT result FROM quiz_map where result_category = '$str' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[0];
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Because you have `LIMIT 1` which limits the return result set to just 1... remove that from `$query`

Comment: are you asking why a query with `LIMIT 1` returns only 1 result?

Comment: plus, you are only echoing the first position, even if you remove the **LIMIT 1** you will still get only one value

Comment: You also have to put `$row= mysqli_fetch_array` in a `while` loop as `mysqli_fetch_array` only gets one row at a time.

Comment: if by category `BC` you mean that it belongs to the categories B and C, then you should rethink your database structure. Never store multiple values in one column.

Comment: From your image, you'll get only 1 as you have an `=` which means is equal to. Switch your statment to `where result_category LIKE '%$str%'` or just rework your database structure as this will likely have problems in the future.

Comment: Thank you so much everybody for your help. I removed limit 1 and added a while loop and it worked. I am just a student knows nothing about this. This is project is a requirement for my school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many things wrong with your code!

**As pointed by** `@IsThisJavascript` and `@Cashbee`:

- You are executing a query with a `LIMIT 1` statement, it will only return **one** record.

**As pointed by myself**:

- Doing `echo $row[0]` will have the same result, if you are only echoing the first value of the array you can't expect to have multiples can you?

**As pointed by** `@IsThisJavascript`:

- You need to loop the results array, like so:

> ```
>  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
>      echo $row['result_category'];  
>  }
> ```

- Consider switching the query from a `'='` to a `'%like%'` statement, to maximize results if you want to get the values that partionaly cointain the string.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I removed the limit 1 and added the while loop and it worked.